# Parsing String by pattern of substrings

Tags: java

I need to parse a formula and get all the variables that were used. The list of variables is available. For example, the formula looks like this:

```
String f = "(Min(trees, round(Apples1+Pears1,1)==1&&universe==big)*number";
```

I know that possible variables are:

```
String[] vars = {"trees","rivers","Apples1","Pears1","Apricots2","universe","galaxy","big","number"};
```

I need to get the following array:

```
String[] varsInF = {"trees", "Apples1","Pears1", "universe", "big","number"};
```

I believe that split method is good here but can’t figure the regexp required for this.

Comment: What's the definition of a variable in your formula? I mean, other than eyeballing it, how can you tell? `Min` isn't one, neither is `1`

Comment: If it is included in "vars" array then it is our variable.

Comment: So your problem statement really is, "find all the tokens that exist in a string based on a predefined list". Regex is the wrong tool for this problem.

Comment: This is not the type of expression where a regular expression would work, not least because this is not a regular language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for any regex pattern - just check which item of the supported `vars` is contained in the given string:

```
List<String> varsInf = new ArrayList<>();
for(String var : vars)
    if(f.contains(var))
        varsInf.add(var);
```

Using `Stream<>` you can:

```
String[] varsInf = Arrays.stream(vars).filter(f::contains).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: Thank you! ArrayList is perfect here for me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "variable" is represented by one alphanumeric character or sequential sequence of multiple such characters, you should split by not-alphanumeric characters, i. e. `[^\w]+`, then collect result by iteration or filter:

```
Set<String> varSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(vars));
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();     
for (String s : f.split("[^\\w]+")) {
    if (varSet.contains(s)) {
        result.add(s);
    }
}
```